# Is it possible to update GitLab CE from the latest version after customizing it's code

Tags: updates, gitlab-ce

I have on premise GitLab CE installation, which is customized by our development team. Is it possible to update our code by all latest GitLab CE features?

The original version was CE 15.7. We are developing our features about a year, so we have lots of changes in the source code. Our business asks as to get all the latest features from the current GitLab CE version. As far as I understand, it's impossible. Am I right?

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book/technologie recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)